# Flutter appbar overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

Im following a turtorial on flutter but i get a overflow error on the appbar in my emulator.
The appbar worked fine when only the PopupMenyButton was there.
Then I added this custom badge-widget, which returns a stack-widget on the appbar.
I think somehow the stack-widget (Badge) overfloows the appbar, but i cant figure out how I can constrain it.

```
Error message:
Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99655 pixels on the right.
```

[Emulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR9Ad.png)

main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/providers/cart.dart';

import 'providers/product.dart';
import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './screens/products_overview_screen.dart';
import './providers/products_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Products(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Cart(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyShop',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        home: ProductsOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

cart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  late Map<String, CartItem> _items;

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items == null ? 0 : _items.length;
  }

  void addItem(
    String productId,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      _items.update(
        productId,
        (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
            id: existingCartItem.id,
            title: existingCartItem.title,
            price: existingCartItem.price,
            quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1),
      );
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
          id: DateTime.now().toString(),
          title: title,
          price: price,
          quantity: 1,
        ),
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

product:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

products_provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/providers/product.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/widgets/product_item.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  //var _showFavoritesOnly = false;

  List<Product> get items {
    //if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    // return _items.where((ProductItem) => ProductItem.isFavorite).toList();
    //}
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  //void showFavoritesOnly() {
  // _showFavoritesOnly = true;
  // notifyListeners();
  //}

  // void showAll() {
  //  _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  //  notifyListeners();
  // }

  void addProduct() {
    // _items.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

product_detail_screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/providers/products_provider.dart';
import '../providers/products_provider.dart';

class ProductDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductDetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routName = '/product-detail';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).findById(productId);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

products_overview_screen:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:shop_app/providers/cart.dart';
    
    import '../widgets/products_grid.dart';
    import '../providers/products_provider.dart';
    import '../widgets/badge.dart';
    
    enum FilterOptions {
      Favourites,
      All,
    }

    class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<ProductsOverviewScreen> createState() => _ProductsOverviewScreenState();
    }
    
    class _ProductsOverviewScreenState extends `State<ProductsOverviewScreen> {`

  var _showOnlyFavorites = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyShop'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (FilterOptions selectedValue) {
              setState(() {
                if (selectedValue == FilterOptions.Favourites) {
                  _showOnlyFavorites = true;
                } else {
                  _showOnlyFavorites = false;
                }
              });
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (_) => [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: Text('Only Favorites'),
                    value: FilterOptions.Favourites,
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: Text('Show All'),
                    value: FilterOptions.All,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Consumer<Cart>(
                builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
                  child: ch as Widget,
                  value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_cart,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: ProductsGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
        );
      }
    }
```

products_grid:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:shop_app/providers/products_provider.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/widgets/product_item.dart';

class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showFavs;

  ProductsGrid(this.showFavs);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = showFavs ? productsData.favoriteItems : productsData.items;

    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[i],
        child: ProductItem(
            // products[i].id,
            //products[i].title,
            //products[i].imageUrl,
            ),
      ),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10),
    );
  }
}
```

product_item:

```
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String id;
  //final String title;
  //final String imageUrl;

  //ProductItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ProductDetailScreen.routName,
              arguments: product.id,
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavoriteStatus();
              },
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () {
              cart.addItem(product.id, product.price, product.title);
            },
            color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

badge:

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Badge extends StatelessWidget {
  const Badge({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.value,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final String value;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        child,
        Positioned(
          right: 8,
          top: 8,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            // color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              color: color != null
                  ? color
                  : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 16,
              minHeight: 16,
            ),
            child: Text(
              value,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the emulator error was due to the late initialization of the item list. Change late to the nullable datatype.

**Make these changes to your Cart.dart:**

```
class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> ?_items;// <------_items can be null

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items!};  //<-----added null check
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items == null ? 0 : _items!.length;//<----added null check
  }

  void addItem(
      String productId,
      double price,
      String title,
      ) {
    if (_items!.containsKey(productId)) {   //<----added null check
      _items!.update(  //<-----added null check
        productId,
            (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
            id: existingCartItem.id,
            title: existingCartItem.title,
            price: existingCartItem.price,
            quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1),
      );
    } else {
      _items!.putIfAbsent(   //<-----added null check
        productId,
            () => CartItem(
          id: DateTime.now().toString(),
          title: title,
          price: price,
          quantity: 1,
        ),
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image: Emulator]

Comment: I tried your code in a separate project and i got the same error in the appbar with the pixel overflow. Its maybe something with the emulator ive choosed that differs?

Comment: The error that occurred above is not due to size, it is the provider's error. Did you wrap your ProductsOverviewScreen inside Provider while routing from the MyApp screen? as I've done it. Or maybe you can share your entire code then I will be able to answer it properly.

Comment: Ok, i see im just starting to learn about Provider but i think thats what I (the turtorial) have done in the main class? Ive updated the post with all the code

Comment: And also, are you sure it has nothing to do with size? what does the error message: "A RenderFlex overflowed by 99655 pixels on the right" mean?

Comment: Try the latest update.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really have to learn about null saftey, would never figured this out.

Comment: You're welcome and please upvote the answer if you think this answers your question.

Comment: Ofc,I tried, but I havent got enough "reputation" to do that... I will when I get enough.

Comment: Now I have 15 reputaion @dartKnightRises!